# Creating a method must check which of the two numbers is larger, and execute an increasing count from the smallest to the largest

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, using

Ok so i need to Create a method in the LogicalOp class, which will receive two number parameters. The method must check which of the two numbers is larger, and execute an increasing count from the smallest to the largest. (Eg: if x is the first parameter and int y is the second, if x is greater than y, then the count is from y to x).

I have tried different methods but they either did not do anything or go for an infinite loop. I don't know how to stop a loop from x to y if the x is smaller then y and from x the count starts to y and then stop there to the biggest number i imputed in console.

```
public void getForthExercise() {
    System.out.println("Give the x parameter and y ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int y = in.nextInt();
    if (x > y) {
        for (int i = x; i >= y; i++)
            System.out.println(i);

    } else if (x < y) {
        for (int i = y; i >= x;i++ )
            System.out.println(i);
```

So if i imput x=25 and y=5 || y

Comment: If `x > y` then you want `i` to have a starting value of `y`, not `x`. Then you would loop while `i < x` or `i <= x`, depending on if you want the value of `x` to be included.

Comment: you are starting from bigger number and going towards more bigger numbers by using i++, either start from smaller number & come towards smaller number using i++ or start from bigger and go towards smaller number using i--.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give you a hint how to simplify the problem: you do not need to care about x < y, or y > x for looping.

You only care: about the smaller number of that pair, and the larger number!

In other words: you simply have to loop from min(x, y) to max(x, y).

Think about it: for what needs to be printed, does it really matter whether x is 5 or 25, or whether y is 25 or 5? No, the only thing that matters is: you got 5, and 25. Which one came in first, and which one second, that doesn't change anything about the expected output!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
int min = Math.min(x, y);
int max = Math.max(x, y);
for(int i = min; i < max; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```